# Replace first vowel in word but not second vowel, aka. lew language

Tags: python, encryption, encoding

So what I'm trying to achieve is a program that can encode and decode the "Löffelsprache" which is a German fun encoding

It work as follows:
every vowel gets replaced by "the vowel itself" + short + "the vowel again"
Default short is "lew";
e.g.: hello > he*lew*ello*lew*o

I got that working with my code, but it's messy and not the most elegant solution.

Also there are rules that "ear" would not translate "e*lew*ea*lew*ar" but just "e*lew*ear".

So if there's a second vowel right after, it's ignored.

For better understanding, I found this online generator that uses "b" as short:
https://de.toolpage.org/tool/bsprache

Code:

```
# Get user input
inputtextraw = input("What to en/decrypt?\n").lower()
# set the message to be translated (inputtext)
inputtext = inputtextraw
# set the short
shortraw = "lew"

# Set a placeholder so the following replace functions don't replace part of the previously placed short
short_placeholder = "@"


# Find out if it's already encoded or needs to be encoded
if "a" + shortraw + "a" in inputtext or "e" + shortraw + "e" in inputtext or "i" + shortraw + "i" in inputtext or "o" + shortraw + "o" in inputtext or "u" + shortraw + "u" in inputtext:
    # DECODE
    try:
        # Replace all shorts with the placeholder
        inputtext = inputtext.replace(shortraw, short_placeholder)
        # Decode
        inputtext = inputtext.replace("e" + short_placeholder + "e", "e")
        inputtext = inputtext.replace("a" + short_placeholder + "a", "a")
        inputtext = inputtext.replace("i" + short_placeholder + "i", "i")
        inputtext = inputtext.replace("o" + short_placeholder + "o", "o")
        inputtext = inputtext.replace("u" + short_placeholder + "u", "u")
        # Save result
        result = inputtext
    except:
        print("error")
    print('\n"' + inputtextraw + '" means:\n' + result + '\n')
else:
    # ENCODE
    try:
        # Encode to vowel + placeholder + vowel
        inputtext = inputtext.replace("e", "e" + short_placeholder + "e")
        inputtext = inputtext.replace("a", "a" + short_placeholder + "a")
        inputtext = inputtext.replace("i", "i" + short_placeholder + "i")
        inputtext = inputtext.replace("o", "o" + short_placeholder + "o")
        inputtext = inputtext.replace("u", "u" + short_placeholder + "u")
        # replace the placeholder with the actual short
        result = inputtext.replace(short_placeholder, shortraw)
    except:
        print("error")
    print('\n"' + inputtextraw + '" in ' + shortraw + ' code is:\n' + result + '\n')
```

Comment: You got mixed up in the encode case. It should be: `result = inputtext.replace(short_placeholder, shortraw)`. But the rule in which it should be translated to "elewear" isn't correct. You change all occurrences if you only see one, this logic is flawed.

Comment: my bad, probably happened when cleaning up the code

Comment: While encoding, maybe you should take an approach of building a new word, and not replacing existing letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `replace()` for encoding just iterate over your string and check each character if it is in a list of characters / vowel or not.

Cause you want to skip the encoding on the second vowel you have to check if the last character was encoded or not before processing the next one:

```
data = []

for c in inputtext:
    if c in vList and not data:
        data.append(c+shortraw+c)
    elif c in vList and shortraw not in data[-1]:
        data.append(c+shortraw+c)
    else:
        data.append(c)

newString = ''.join(data)
```

In the end you have to `join()` the generated resultset to a new string.

#### Example

```
# Get user input
inputtextraw = input("What to en/decrypt?\n").lower()
# set the message to be translated (inputtext)
inputtext = inputtextraw
# set the short
shortraw = "lew"
# list of characters to check
vList = ['a','e','i','o','u']

def is_encoded(inputtext,shortraw):
    for c in vList: 
        if c+shortraw+c in inputtext:
            return True

    return False

def decode_string(inputtext,shortraw):
    for c in vList:
        inputtext = inputtext.replace(c+shortraw, '')
    return inputtext

def encode_string(inputtext,shortraw):
    data = []

    for c in inputtext:
        if c in vList and not data:
            data.append(c+shortraw+c)
        elif c in vList and shortraw not in data[-1]:
            data.append(c+shortraw+c)
        else:
            data.append(c)

    return ''.join(data)

if is_encoded(inputtext,shortraw):
    #decode
    print(f'String is encoded -> decoded string is {decode_string(inputtext,shortraw)}')
else:
    #encode
    print(f'String is not encoded\n"{inputtextraw}" in {shortraw} code is:\n {encode_string(inputtext,shortraw)} \n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a simple regex to be elegant.

Capture a vowel that is not followed by another vowel, then replace the captured vowel with itself, `lew`, then itself again.

Code: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4WvUZs/1))

```
re.sub(r'([a-z])(?![a-z])', r'\1lew\1', inputtext)
```